# Questions on proof. Every convergent sequence is bounded. (Abbott pp 45 t2.3.2)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

(http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Convergent_Sequence_is_Bounded)

Posit: $\{x_n\}$ is a [sequence](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Sequence) in $\mathbb{C}$.
Posit: $x_n \to L$ as $n \to \infty$.

**Modus operandi.** From the definition of [[Definition:Bounded Sequence|bounded sequence]], we need to find $K$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \left|{x_n}\right| \le K$. Videlicet, we need to find an upper bound for $x_n$ (as Umberto P. commented)

Since $\{x_n\}$ converges, it is true
: $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists N: n > N \implies \left|{x_n - l}\right| < \epsilon$.
<s>In particular, this is true when $\epsilon = 1$.</s>  [$e$ can be any > 0, not just 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/532637/85079). Ergo I conserve $e$.
I don't know why, but Abbott and Proofwiki select $e = 1$ instead.

By the agency of Reverse Triangle Inequality:  $\forall n > N: \color{magenta}{\left|{x_n}\right| - \left|{l}\right| } \le \left|{x_n - l}\right| \color{magenta}{< e}$

> **1.** Why Reverse Triangle Inequality ? Why not $|x_n - l| < e \iff -e < x_n - l < e \iff -e + l < \color{seagreen}{x_n < e + l} \implies \not\Leftarrow \color{seagreen}{|x_n| < |e + l| }   $

That is, $\color{magenta}{\left|{x_n}\right| < \left|{l}\right| + e}$.

[image]

> **2.** Why 'worry'? What are the flubs or obstacles? How does this affect $M$?

Comment: Why do you need to be clairvoyant or vatic for [1] and [2]? When you read a proof you're not being told "here's a bunch of stuff you should already know" you're being told "here's an argument that works".

Comment: [1] You are just picking an upper bound. [2] You are being vatic, you are just trying to bound $x_n$ [3] Because the upper bound you found in [2] may not work for those terms that come before.

Comment: @UmbertoP. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **1.** Why Reverse Triangle Inequality ? Why not $|x_n - l| < e \iff -e < x_n - l < e \iff -e + l < \color{seagreen}{x_n < e + l} \implies \not\Leftarrow \color{seagreen}{|x_n| < |e + l| }   $

Well I don't  know if you notice that your method uses at least $3$ more implications than in the use of the triangle inequality. Furthermore what you have done is nothing but apply the triangle inequality. We have already done this before and have generalised it and called it the triangle inequality for convenience, ease and time conservation.

> **2.** Why 'worry'? What are the flubs or obstacles? How does this affect $M$?

Well consider the sequence $\color{tomato}{100, 100, 100, 100, 1, \frac {1}{2}}, \frac {1}{3}, \frac {1}{3}, \frac {1}{4},...$.

The sequence converges to $l = 0$. (You need to check this for yourself. It won't help you if you post another query asking why). Let $\epsilon = 1 $, which is what Abbott and Proofwiki used to bound this sequence.
Then for the sequence I constructed, observe for $n \ge 6$ (videlicet, after the orange terms), $ |x_n| \lt 1 + |l| = 1 $. But $1$ is not even close to being a bound for $(x_n)$ which includes terms equal to $100$. So you also need to consider $M = \text{Max} \{|x_1|, |x_2|,|x_3|,|x_4|, |x_5|\} = 100$.
 Now we consider $N = \text{Max} \{M,  1 + |l| \}$. Then you should be able to see than $|x_n| \le N$ for every natural number $n$.

Not only does this work. But these considerations are **necessary**. You will also do well to heed the comment by Umberto.

Comment: thanks. +Upvote. Patrick Da Silva answered **1** too, ergo i understand why it's better. however, i want to clarify. you say i used 'triangle inequality'. but i didn't? i only took off the absolute value? isn't this more natural?

Comment: Yes but that is essentially what the triangle inequality does(What you did can be used to prove the triangle inequality in $\Bbb R$).  It transforms a bound for $|x_n - l|$  into a bound for $|x_n|$ There is nothing wrong with what you did. But you are better off practicing using the triangle inequality since it will come in handy when you learn Analysis further and extend to spaces beyond the real line.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

More importantly, the reason why you don't want to do 1. is because you're computing inequalities on complex numbers, which doesn't make sense ; i.e. you can't "take off the absolute values" as you wish. The inequality $|x_n| - |\ell| \le |x_n - \ell|$ is therefore relevant.

You don't really have to fix $\varepsilon = 1$, but it's nice to have some number that's not arbitrary.

If you don't feel like worrying about the first $N$ terms, then don't worry about it, but still prove that the sequence is bounded =) that is, find an $M$ such that the open ball around $0$ contains them ; this is what the author does.

Hope that helps,